# SQL - Trying to find max count between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

So I have two tables, STOPS_AT and POINT_OF_INTEREST, which are like this:

STOPS_AT[**Route_ID, Stop_ID**]

and

POINT_OF_INTEREST[**Stop_ID, Name**, Category]

Now I am trying to select the Route_ID who has the most number of stops at a point of interest. In other words, the route who has the most number of stops, who also appear in the POINT_OF_INTEREST table. I have tried the following:

```
select Route_ID
from (select Route_ID, count(POINT_OF_INTEREST.Stop_ID) as cnt
  from STOPS_AT R
  group by Route_ID
 ) rc join
 (select max(cnt) as maxcnt
  from (select Route_ID, count(POINT_OF_INTEREST.Stop_ID) as cnt
        from STOPS_AT
        group by Route_ID
       ) rc
 ) m
 on rc.cnt = m.maxcnt;
```

However this doesn't seem to work, saying it is unaware of the POINT_OF_INTEREST table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't join to the `point_of_interest` table -- that's why you're receiving the error.  You are trying to count a field you are not selecting from.

If you don't need to worry about ties, one easy way would be to use `limit`:

```
select route_id
from (
   select sa.route_id, count(*) cnt
   from stops_at sa
       join point_of_interest poi on sa.route_id = poi.route_id
   group by sa.route_id
) t
order by cnt desc
limit 1
```

---

If ties are a concern, then you can alter your query using the above:

```
select Route_ID
from (
       select sa.route_id, count(*) cnt
       from stops_at sa
           join point_of_interest poi on sa.route_id = poi.route_id
       group by sa.route_id
 ) rc join
 (select max(cnt) as maxcnt
  from (
           select sa.route_id, count(*) cnt
           from stops_at sa
               join point_of_interest poi on sa.route_id = poi.route_id
           group by sa.route_id
       ) rc
 ) m
 on rc.cnt = m.maxcnt;
```

Comment: Providing that the maximum belongs just to a single route.

Comment: @PM77-1 -- yes, agreed.  If needed, OP can look into mysql rankings to support ties generally created with `user-defined variables`.  Alternatively, can use this subquery in place of mistaken one posted.

Comment: Only issue was this line:
    join POINT_OF_INTEREST poi on sa.Stop_ID = poi.Stop_ID